# JQUERY - Methods not working after for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### Background

I am learning JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT. I have come across a bizarre issue if someone could explain why it is happening. Essentially I have a simple 4 item list. Code is meant to do the following:

1. Using .remove() remove Item Four
2. Using JS For loop go throughlist change the content matching the condition (content of li#three).
3. Using .remove(), li#one is removed
4. Using .text() change li#three text content to Change3

#### Problem

My problem is steps 1 and 2 **work**. But the methods after the loop ie .remove() and text() **do not work**. Also if I put these methods infront of the loop it works.

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong and possible work-arounds? Thank you in advance.

PS I am using Dreamweaver as my editor.

Ka Tech

#### Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('li#four').remove();
    var $length = $('li').length;
    for (var i=0;i<=$length;i++)
    {
        var $item = $('li')[i].textContent;
        if ($item === "Item Two")
        {
            $('li')[i].textContent= "Change2";
        }
    }
    $('li#one').remove();
    $('li#three').text('Change3');

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="list">
    <h2> List </h2>
    <li id=one class=hot>Item One</li>
    <li id=two>Item Two</li>
    <li id=three>Item Three</li>
    <li id=four>Item Four </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow that's lightning fast response. Thank you so much. Arun your explanation is spot on thank you for explaining it too me. Also I was wondering how to use the .each() with conditions. Its more efficient and will use that in future. One question to add. I am used to VB where errors are told during the compiling. For this case I had no errors. How do I catch them? Is there specific debug/editor you are using which you can recommend? Thanks in advance.

Comment: All good, Chrome has a debgugger! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have a script error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined`. That is because `var $length = $('li').length` will give you 3, and your for loop iterate from `i=0` to `i<=3` but when `i==3` there is no `li` element at index 3 so `$('li')[i]` will return undefined causing the error

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $length = $('li').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < $length; i++) {
        var $item = $('li')[i].textContent;
        if ($item === "Item Two") {
            $('li')[i].textContent = "Change2";
        }
    }
    $('li#one').remove();
    $('li#three').text('Change3');

});
```

---

Another way

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() === "Item Two") {
            $(this).text('Change2')
        }
    })

    $('#one').remove();
    $('#three').text('Change3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2> List </h2>
<ul class="list">
    <li id=one class=hot>Item One</li>
    <li id=two>Item Two</li>
    <li id=three>Item Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vsmLvzL9/)**

```
var $length = $('li').length;
for (var i = 0; i <= $length; i++) {
    var $item = $('li').eq(i).text();
    if ($item === "Item Two") {
        $('li').eq(i).text("Change2");
    }
}
$('#one').remove();
$('#three').text('Change3');
```